# Find ELB Loadbalancer with the help of ACM certificate ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-elb, aws-acm

Is there any way that we can know which Loadbalancer ELB an ACM certificate is attached to if we have the ARN for the ACM certificate ?

I know the opposite is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The ACM [DescribeCertificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeCertificate.html) API response includes an "InUseBy" property that is a list of ARNs representing the AWS resources using the certificate.

Comment: Thank You @mark-b !  I tried to get the same by running AWS CLI 'aws acm describe-certificate --certificate-arn <arn >|grep -i inuse ' but it gives me o/p as below ->
        "InUseBy": [], .  But I know that this cert is added to an LB.

Comment: You can verify you have the correct certificate ARN, and see the "inUseBy" list in the AWS ACM web console.

Comment: Sorry my bad Mark! I am able to view my ACM cert is being used by which services. I tweaked my command a bit to get desired output ->  'aws acm describe-certificate --certificate-arn <arn >|grep -ia10 inuseby '